# Entity framework: how to read current data after delete from referenced table

Tags: entity-framework

I have three tables Job, Contact and a reference table between them named JobContact. When I delete a record from JobContact table, so record is deleted from database, but it is still present in code. I mean, when I do a select Job by key and when I'm accessing job.JobContact, so record is still there.

How can I force EF to get the current data from this table?

Edited:

I'm using EF to delete the record. Here is a code sample how I'm doing it:

Step 1: delete record from JobContact:

```
var jobContactRepos = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository<JobContact>();    
var jobContact = jobContactRepos.SelectByKey(jobContactId);

jobContactRepos.Delete(jobContact);
jobContactRepos.Save();
```

Step 2: get the job record from DB after step 1 is done:

```
var jobRepos = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository<Job>();
var job = jobRepos.SelectByKey(id);
```

After Step 1, record is deleted from DB: it is OK.

After Step 2, record is still present in the job.JobContact entity: it is not OK.

RepositoryFactory creates already a new context. So I don't understant. In which place in my code should I use Refresh() method?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dispose your EF context and create a new one, this will force EF to get fresh data from the DB instead of using possibly cached data. Alternatively you can call [`Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503718.aspx) on your context using `RefreshMode.StoreWins`.

But the real question is why do you delete this record from the database directly and don't use EF for it? Had you used the EF context to remove the `Contact` entity from the `Contacts` navigation property collection of your `Job` entity, this problem shouldn't be there in the first place.

**Edit:**

The reference table should be represented in EF as a navigation property `Contacts` in your `Job` entities, and a navigation property `Jobs` in your `Contact` entities. Are you using an older version of EF (I am probably not familiar enough with previous versions) or have a custom repository layer that introduces this reference entity?

Comment: I have edited my question, because I cannot answer. Can you take a look on it pls. thx.

Comment: you are right, I od not dispose object context. it was a problem. because repository was created by IoC and the default life cycle was singleton.